# HTTP 405 Error? Post method works on one page but not the other (AJAX, Jquery, $.post)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I am completely baffled by the trouble I'm having.

I have a website hosted in IIS (in testing phase so everything is through localhost)

IIS 7.5

In my homepage (written in HTML), I'm using a PHP script ($.post method) to communicate with a WCF service to authenticate users (works perfectly).

I also have a Registration page, that communicates with the same WCF web service using a different php script.  However, when I try to use the $.post method, I get an HTTP 405 error.  What's killing me is that I do not understand how it can work perfect on one page, and complain on another?

I'm calling my $.post method on my Homepage like this:

```
 $.post('authenticate.php', $("#frmLogin").serialize(), function(data) {
                        //do stuff  
                });
```

No problems.

Same method on a different html page calling different php script:

```
 $.post('registration.php', $("#frmRegister").serialize(), function(data) {
                            //do stuff
                    });
```

and I get HTTP 405 error - Method not allowed.

What could possibly be the culprit?  I've added .php to the IIS handler mappings and I allow ALL verbs but same problem.  I've tried changing my WCF method to "POST" instead of "GET" (my authenticate is using GET which works) but still a problem.

**Update:**

Here's the php code of the registration.php file

```
         <?php


    $UserName = $_POST['UserName'];
    $PassWord = $_POST['PassWord'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];


    $wcfClient = new SoapClient('http://localhost/AYAFYAuthenticate/AuthenticationService.svc?wsdl');

    $args = array('uname' => $UserName,'pword' => $PassWord,'email' => $Email);

    $response = $wcfClient->CreateUser($args);

    echo $response->CreateUserResult;
    ?>
```

Here's the working authentication.php file:

```
         <?php


    $UserName = $_POST['UserName'];
    $PassWord = $_POST['PassWord'];


    $wcfClient = new SoapClient('http://localhost/AYAFYAuthenticate/AuthenticationService.svc?wsdl');

    $args = array('uname' => $UserName,'pword' => $PassWord);

    $response = $wcfClient->Authenticate($args);

    echo $response->AuthenticateResult;
    ?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html shows how to fix 405 errors. From reading there, I'm assuming it's something server side. If you'd post the php it would be helpful

Comment: I updated my question with the php scripts but I will look at this link you provided.

Comment: Try this. Replace your registration code temporarily with your auth code to see whether it's client side. Idk what your "do stuff" code is, if there is code there, but doing this step should test whether its a client side or server side issue. I don't see anything really wrong with the php, but I'm not a big php coder to begin with so I'll poke someone to take a look